# Combining classic promises with async

Tags: javascript, es6-promise

Is this code correct? Can I combine promises like that?

```
var data = {}
await getInfo(data.com)
 .then(result => {data = result})
 .catch(error => {})
doStuffOnlyAfterGetInfo(data)
```

Comment: why do you want to do this?

Comment: Why not just try it?

Comment: try {
  const data = await getInfo(data.com)
} catch(e) {
}

Comment: Yes. It is working. But I'm thinking maybe there is some downsides and its not recommended to do this?

Comment: I'm doing it because I like it better than using try catch

Comment: If that is exactly your code, you can just write `const data = await getInfo(data2.com).catch(() => {}); doStuffOnlyAfterGetInfo(data);` instead.

Comment: Correction: It should be `.catch(() => ({}))`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes, you can do that, you can think of `await` like this:

`await x` where `x` is a Promise OR any value. In your case that chain call returns a promise.

all of this works:

```
async function fn() {
  try {
    var a = await 20; // a = 20
    var b = Promise.resolve(20); // b = 20
    var c = Promise.reject(20); // This throws exception
    var d = Promise.reject(20).catch(() => 30) // d = 30
    var e = fetch(url) // same as fetch(url).then(e => /*...*/)
    var f = fetch(url).then(res => res.json())
  catch (e) {
    console.log(e) // 20
  }
}
```

Also don't forget, that you can only use `await` in `async` functions.

[Seed the Docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/await)

Comment: But is it a best practice or make the code less effective?

Answer (score 1):

You can, since `promise.then()` and `promise.catch()` return promises as well.

You can do the same without `then\catch` using `try\catch`

```
async function getInfo(url)
{
   try{
     const result = await fetch(url);
     return {data: result};
   }
   catch(e){

   }
}
```